# What would be an exact word to describe taking solace in other's misfortune, knowing one is not alone in facing it?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

Schadenfreude implies deriving 'pleasure' in other's misfortune but what I am looking for is a word where one derives comfort that one's misfortune is faced by others as well. For instance, knowing at the workplace that you are not the sole employee being offered lower benefits by your employer, despite increasing workload. Another (morbid) instance is during a plane about to crash, you derive comfort from the fact that you are not the only one who's going to die.

Edit:

Below answers point to a positive connotation. I am looking for a word that carries a negative connotation. Continuing with the above example, it would be bad to take comfort that others too are being overworked, rather than quitting that job and switching over to something else. Or try to devise some sort of escape from the crashing plane.

Comment: It sounds like you are describing "lucky" or "fortunate" but those words don't  address membership.  Can't wait for the answer.  I don't think there is a word like that.

Comment: "To be in good company"?

Comment: There's the old expression "misery loves company".  And one might suggest *schadenfreude*, except that that implies taking pleasure in another's misery, vs deriving comfort from it.

Answer (score 3):

A ***[trouble shared is a trouble halved](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/trouble+shared+is+a+trouble+halved)***, may suggest what you are referring to:

> - Prov. If you tell someone about a problem you are having, or request someone's help with a problem, the problem will not seem so daunting. (Can be used to encourage someone to confide in you or ask for your help.)
>
>   - *Jill: Is something wrong? You've seemed so depressed lately. Jane: Oh, I wouldn'twant to bother you with it. Jill: Don't be silly. A trouble shared is a trouble halved, remember.*

(McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs.)

Comment: Edited my question. I am looking for a word with a negative connotation.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a single word, let's try **solidarity**.  Google gives one of the meanings as "mutual support within a group."

You can also say

> ... and then I didn't feel **so alone** [in my troubles, or whatever].

The phrase given by Josh61 is lovely if you don't mind the length.

Comment: Edited my question. I am looking for a word with a negative connotation.

Answer (score 1):

(Fresh start, going for the negative connotation.)

**Misery loves company**

Google gave me: "People who are unhappy may get some consolation from knowing that others are unhappy too. The American Heritage® New Dictionary of Cultural Literacy, Third Edition."